# Pruning directories and current directory's files for use with tar

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, tar

I've looked at numerous articles and I can't seem to figure it out, I suppose I'm a noob.

Anyways I have a directory that I would like to tar, however I want to exclude the shallow directory's files, as well as exclude the folders
"plugins", "backups", and "logs" that are located in the shallow directory.

->

```
\#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p /path/to/backup/directory/`date +%d%m%y`
cd /path/to/backup/directory/`date +%d%m%y`
cd .. | find . -not \\( -path plugins -prune -o -path backups -prune -o -path logs -prune \\) -mindepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0 tar cpj --directory=$(cd -) -f `date +%H`.tar.gz
```

The find section is what's wrong, it doesn't exclude anything. This is my 30th (not literally but probably higher than that actually xD ) attempt to prune and what not, with each attempt looking more ridiculous than the last.

If someone could just show me a solution for the find section, that'd be great - thanks

(the '`' characters are around the dates, it just breaks the code view when I try to put them in there)

Comment: Why don't you just use the --exclude=PATTERN option of tar?

Comment: `cd` produces no meaningful output to `find`, and the change is local to the process started for that component of the pipeline anyway.

Comment: I concur with `mfnalex`, `tar` has flexible ways to include/exclude files, and you should try `man tar`.  You can use a file to list inclusion/exclusion specifications, and you can build a file on demand with a process substitution (`<(command_or_function)`) to avoid working with regular files.

Comment: I did, I'm just unsure of how to exclude the shallow folder's files, the other folders I figured out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use --exclude=PATTERN and `*/`, as it will only catch directories:

```
tar --exclude=plugins/ --exclude=logs/ --exclude=backups/ -cf /path/to/backup/directory/`date +%d%m%y`/whatever.tar [other options] */
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that and I've gotten it to exclude the folders, but idk how to exclude files only in the shallow directory

Comment: Can you show the output of ls when you are in the directory and tell what files exactly should be excluded?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/7aafd163d105d6cf68b864a43fef513d I'm trying to backup only the folders, excluding plugins and logs. So the result in this case should be a tar of msffamap + temp + world + world_nether + world_the_end

Comment: You could try this:

cd /path/to/minecraftserver && tar -cf /path/to/backup/directory/\`date +%d%m%y\` --exclude=plugins --exclude=logs */

Comment: Thanks! that works - just have to leave out the slashes on the ends of the exclude folders :)

Comment: Yes, you are right - I checked my own backup script and I didn't but the slashes either. Good luck with your server

Answer (score 0):

About find excluding directories, try

```
find . -type d \( -path plugins -o -path backups -o -path logs \) -prune -o -print
```

Comment: I just tried, unfortunately nothing was excluded :( Thanks though